# How do I display these set of numbers with only one print command?

Tags: python

```py
[1 3 6 5 7 10 9 11 14 13 15 18 17 19 22 21 23 26]
```

I have to display these numbers with only one `print` command and a `while` loop.
I got it with several print commands but when I was challenged to use one, I just couldn't figure it out.(beginner btw)

Comment: Do you want them to be printed out on the console one by one each on its own line?

Comment: `for i in [1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 10, 9, 11, 14, 13, 15, 18, 17, 19, 22, 21, 23, 26]: print(i)`?

Comment: How does a ``while`` loop come into the picture here? Is there some formula for computing these numbers iteratively?

Comment: Do you mean `print(*my_list)`?

Comment: Add your current code with multiple print statements to your question. It would make much easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: while y<23:
  print(y,end =" ")  
  print(y+2,end =" ")  
  y+=2
  print(y+3,end =" ")
  y+=2

Comment: I'm supposed to understand the relationship between the number and continue the series.

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69119766/edit) button.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. got the answers. will do better next time!

Answer (score 1):

Your list follows a pattern, it is `+2 +3 -1`. So, you can just write something like the following code

```
index = 0
number = 1
while(index < 18):
   print(number)
   index += 1
   if(index%3 == 1):
       number += 2
   elif(index%3 == 2):
       number += 3
   elif(index%3 == 0):
       number -= 1
```